# Python : Copying the data from one excel file to another excel file (template) and save it as new excel file without any data loss

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl, shutil

I have an excel sheet (with the first row having numbers) named `template.xlsx`.It contains data in the sheet named ***‘data’*** as follows

[image: Sample Excel File]

it also has a graph in the second sheet named ***graph*** like this
[image: Random Graph]

I have a ***csv file*** named `input.csv` which has data in the similar format as `template.xlsx` but has more columns than it and the first row **doesn’t** have the numbers.
[image]

I want to copy the data from `input.csv` to the first sheet of `template.xlsx` so that the graph according to the data in `input.csv` will be generated in second sheet.

For this, I am making another excel file `output.xlsx` which should first take in all the data from `template.xlsx`, empty itself (since number of columns in `template.xlsx` and `input.csv` are different) and copy data from `input.csv` in it and generate graph accordingly (I need to retain the `template.xlsx` and dont want to over write it,also, in the `output.xlsx` I want the first row to be there too).

I did this but I am not able to accomplish the required task.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import openpyxl
from shutil import copyfile

template_file = 'template.xlsx' #Has numbers in row 1 already
output_file = 'output.xlsx' #What we are saving the template as

copyfile(template_file, output_file)

# Read in the data to be pasted into the termplate
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv') #to read the csv file

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_file)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('data') 

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python (openpyxl) : Put data from one excel file to another (template file) & save it with another name while retaining the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610870/python-openpyxl-put-data-from-one-excel-file-to-another-template-file-sa)

Comment: That is my question only which I had asked earlier
I have linked it here.

Comment: Still asked the same question twice…

Comment: simplified and shortened the question